# I'm getting a ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass when I deploy to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rack, spree, webrick

I'm running rails 4.0.4 with Spree 2-2-stable.

Everything runs fine on localhost, but when I tried logging into admin

2014-04-17T21:23:58.859274+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-04-17 21:23:58] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
2014-04-17T21:23:58.859274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:69:in`block in service'
2014-04-17T21:23:58.859274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:451:in `block in each'
2014-04-17T21:23:58.859274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:450:in`each'
2014-04-17T21:23:58.859274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils.rb:450:in `each'
2014-04-17T21:23:58.859274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:63:in`service'
2014-04-17T21:23:58.859274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-04-17T21:23:58.859274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
2014-04-17T21:23:58.859274+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-04-17T21:23:58.870803+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/admin/login host=vaporhop-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=8f86aa09-d55e-4405-9fc7-b5976870eacb fwd="108.6.136.145" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=102ms status=500 bytes=671

it seems to the be same error as this:
http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/01/ruby-on-rails-webrick-error-nomethoderror-undefined-method-split-for-nilnilclass/

but he does not describe how to fix it on heroku

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why heroku was using webrick in the first place, which sucks. I had the unicorn gem in the production group, but it wasn't picking it up. I then moved it out to the main group and I went through this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn#adding-unicorn-to-your-application and the problem went away